# How to update old navigation service

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am looking at the on-line documentation for `NavigationService` and I see that it takes a URI and an object...

The navigation service on my system only takes a URI.

```
public bool Navigate(Uri source);
```

Here is the path to the referenced DLL:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\Silverlight\v4.0\Profile\WindowsPhone71\Microsoft.Phone.dll

Runtime version : v2.0.50727

Version : 7.0.0.0

How can I update my system to use the new navigation service?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `NavigationService` ([reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.navigation.navigationservice%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)) class for Windows Phone 8 contains a single `Navigate` method currently ([reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ms591053%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)):

```
public bool Navigate(
    Uri source
)
```

It is likely you're looking at the documentation for the Windows Presentation Foundation ([reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.navigationservice%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).

I often use the home page for [Windows Phone Development](http://developer.windowsphone.com/en-us) and the search bar at the top to be sure I'm only looking at APIs supported by Windows Phone (it just pre-filters when you use that search). Using a full search engine, like Google, is often misleading as it will point to pages that seem correct as many MSDN pages have a link to the "Windows Phone" on them.

Comment: thanks... it would be nice IF it also took an object !

Comment: If this answered your question, I'd appreciate it if you could accept/up vote.

Comment: And, if you need to pass data, you might consider using the query string portion of the URL to pass the data or an identifier that points to the data stored somewhere else.